# Hard drive spins up, clicks a few times (about 5 / 6) and stops

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clicking-sound

I've got this Harddrive, from Samsung. A few months ago it just started clicking, for no reason. The computer which it was connected to, booted up, it recognised the harddrive in the BIOS settings, but Windows didn't.

I tried connecting it to my drive dock and it got the same symptoms, so it isn't an issue from the computer which it was connected to.

Paying about 500 to 600 euros to recover the data, isn't worth it. So I want to try something back home to recover some data, but I'm not really sure what might be wrong, and for that reason I don't know what to try first?

1. Is it most likely the circuit board, so it's better to try another
   one?
2. Or is it a good idea to open the Harddrive and check if the
   drive's heads getting stuck on the platters?
3. Or just use the fridge for 5 minutes?
4. Something else..?

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Clicking" means it tries to adjust the heads, so it got read problems. Some harddisks have internal data on the disk, and if it can't read that, it'll fail. Opening up the harddrive will contaminate it with dust particles and completely kill it. Trying the fridge won't hurt, but likely won't help. If you don't want to pay 500 EUR, your data is gone. You made backups? :-)

Comment: The minute you open the drive outside of a clean room is the second you make the drive a paper weight